# Compare this topology with the usual topology

Tags: general-topology

I have to compare the following topology with the usual one. Which of them is finer?

$\tau= \{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2:$ for any $(a,b) \in U$ exists  $\epsilon >0 $ where $[a,a+\epsilon] \times [b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon]\subseteq U\}$

By definition, $\tau\subseteq\tau_u $ if and only if for every $U\in \tau$ implies $U\in \tau_u$

However, how can I compare them using open basis?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $U \in \tau_u$, then for any $(a,b) \in U$, there is a basic open set
   $$
   (a-\delta, a+\delta)\times (b-\delta', b+\delta') \subset U
   $$
   you can take
   $$
   \epsilon = \min\{\delta/2, \delta'/2\}
   $$
   then
   $$
   [a,a+\epsilon]\times [b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon] \subset U
   $$
   Hence $U \in \tau$. So
   $$
   \tau_u \subset \tau
   $$
2. The set
   $$
   [0,1)\times (-1,1) \in \tau\setminus \tau_u
   $$
   Do you see why?

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathar But you have to proof that for every $B\in \beta_u,$ for every $(c,d)\in B$, exists $D\in\beta : (c,d)\in D \subseteq B$ Is that epsilon correct? If I choose $(c,d)\in B=(a-\mu, a+\mu) x (b-\mu_1, b+\mu_1)$ which would be D?

Comment: @Vaidynathar In the second point, why do you chose the set $$
[0,1)\times (-1,1) \in \tau\setminus \tau_u
$$ instead of $$
[0,1]\times [-1,1] \in \tau\setminus \tau_u
$$ Could you explain it please? As these sets are in $\tau$ aren't they supposed to be closed?

Comment: @Blanca: Given $U \in \tau_u$ to show that $U \in \tau$ we just need to show that it has the defining property of the collection $\tau$, namely that for all $\langle a,b \rangle \in U$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $[ a,a+\epsilon ] \times [ b,b+\epsilon ] \subseteq U$.  This is what Prahlad has done.

Comment: @Blanca: As for your second comment, your proposed set $V = [0,1] \times [-1,1]$ does not work because it is not in $\tau$.  Note that $\langle 1,1 \rangle \in V$ but there is no $\epsilon > 0$ such that $[1,1+\epsilon]\times[1,1+\epsilon] \subseteq V$.  Do you see why?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thank you, I understand the second.So regarding to my first comment, Prahlad has used this notation?  $\tau\subseteq\tau_u $ if and only if for every $U\in \tau$ implies $U\in \tau_u$

Comment: Therefore, we can conclude that $\tau$ is $T_2$?

Comment: @Blanca: Yes, this is just the usual subset notation.  (Recall that a topology is just some family (set) of sets, and a topology $\tau^\prime$ is _finer_ than a topology $\tau$ (on the same set) if every $\tau$-open set is also $\tau^\prime$-open, which in turn means that $\tau \subseteq \tau^\prime$.  (But Prahlad actually shows that $\tau_u \subseteq \tau$ (the reverse of what you wrote in your comment above).

Comment: @Blanca: It is quite easy to show that if a topology $\tau_1$ is Hausdorff, then so is every topology finer than $\tau_1$.  (So in this case since $\tau$ is finer than the known Hausdorff topology $\tau_u$, then $\tau$ is also Hausdorff.)